# react radio buttons and state not performing as expected

Tags: reactjs, next.js, radio-button

I know many similar questions have been asked and answered, but I have a React component that has radio buttons that is not performing as expected...

```
const availableClasses = {
  peasant: {
    name: "Peasant",
    cost: 0,
  },
  noble: {
    name: "Noble",
    cost: 12,
  },
  warrior: {
    name: "Warrior",
    cost: 8,
  },
  wizard: {
    name: "Wizard",
    cost: 9,
  },
  trader: {
    name: "Trader",
    cost: 10,
  }
};

...

{Object.entries(availableClasses).map(([key, value]) => (
  <div key={key} className="form-control">
    <label className="label cursor-pointer">
      <span className="label-text">{value.name} - {value.cost}p</span>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="charClass"
        value={key}
        className="radio checked:background-green-500"
        checked={key === charClass}
        onChange={handleClassChange}
      />
    </label>
  </div>
))}
```

When a user clicks a radio button, a certain number of points should be deducted from a total. If the user then selects a different radio, the previous points should be returned to the total, and a different amount of points deducted from their total. However, I cant seem to get the state to update the total points after the user selects a different radio, and I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong. Ive been searching for 2 days, and everything i've found looks like it should work, but it doesnt, and there are no errors thrown. Here is my handler:

```
const handleClassChange = (e: any) => {
  const cls = e.target.value;
  
  if(cls != charClass){
    const refund = freePoints + lastUsed;
    setLast(0);
    setFreePoints(refund);
    
    const cost = availableClasses[cls].cost;
    setLast(cost);
    
    const query = (freePoints - cost) < 0;
    const error = "You do not have enough free points!";
    const cause = freePoints - cost;
    
    if (query) {
      toast.error(error, {
        position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        draggable: false,
      });
    } else {
      setCharClass(cls);
      setFreePoints(cause);
    }
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong, here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you update the state `setFreePoints(refund);` and expecting it to take effect in instant. While in react, the state will update when the react rerender. So, the `freePoints` after the refund still have the previous state value.

```
...
    const refund = freePoints + lastUsed;
    setLast(0); // this code is unnecessary since you set the state again below
    setFreePoints(refund); // here is the main problem
    
    const cost = availableClasses[cls].cost;
    setLast(cost);
    
    const cause = freePoints - cost; // freePoints still has the old value without refund
...
```

You can solve it with:

```js
const handleClassChange = (e: any) => {
  const cls = e.target.value;
  
  if(cls != charClass){
    const refund = freePoints + lastUsed;
    const cost = availableClasses[cls].cost;
    
    const query = (refund - cost) < 0;
    const error = "You do not have enough free points!";
    const cause = refund - cost;
    
    if (query) {
      toast.error(error, {
        position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        draggable: false,
      });
    } else {
      setLast(cost); // last will always start at 0, so we don't need to reset it after a radio clicked
      setCharClass(cls);
      setFreePoints(cause);
    }
  }
};
```

Or, I think you can change the approach (**but this might cause unintended side effect**), since we are using `radio` which will only active one at a time, instead of doing `refund` you can just deduct from `total` every change event.

for the example:

```js
const initialFreePoints = 100 // this is just example
const [freePoints, setFreePoints] = useState(initialFreePoints)
const handleClassChange = (e: any) => {
  const cls = e.target.value;
  const cost = availableClasses[cls].cost;
  const cause = initialFreePoints - cost;
  const query = cause < 0;
  const error = "You do not have enough free points!";
  if (query) {
    toast.error(error, {
      position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
      draggable: false,
    });
    return;
  }
  setCharClass(cls);
  setFreePoints(cause);
};
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but the second part about changing the approach is potentially misleading. It works well as an isolated example, but would cause problems if there are other things subtracting points from the total. In my opinion cutting it out would be best as it's not really relevant to the question, but including a warning that it might have unintended side effects would be fine.

Comment: I got your point, I'll revise it, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Here are the solutions to the two problems:
[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-dawn-383klk?file=/src/App.js:521-1088)

1. You want to set the `selected` attr for the radios. You are currently setting `checked`. `checked` attr is for checkboxes while `selected` attr is for radio buttons

```js
<input
    type="radio"
    name="charClass"
    value={key}
    className="radio checked:background-green-500"
    // You should set the selected attr not checked
    selected={key === characterClass}
    onChange={handleCharChange}
/>
```

2. You should use the functional setState signature when a state depends on another state.

```js
const handleCharChange = (e) => {
    const activeChar = e.target.value;
    const activeCost = availableClasses[activeChar].cost
    // Use the functional signature of setState when updating 
    // other states that depends on another state
    setCharClass(prev => {
      // This logic will update the Total
      if (prev) {
        const newTotal = (total - availableClasses[prev].cost) + activeCost;
        setTotal(newTotal)
      } else {
        setTotal(total + activeCost)
      }
      // This will set Character Class
      return activeChar
    })
  }
```

Comment: Type error: Type '{ type: "radio"; name: string; value: string; className: string; selected: boolean; onChange: (e: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'selected' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.

Comment: So item one on the list of solutions is wrong. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your logic in the `handler` itself, nothing to do with `state` updates, Here It should work with this modification

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";
const availableClasses = {
  peasant: {
    name: "Peasant",
    cost: 0
  },
  noble: {
    name: "Noble",
    cost: 12
  },
  warrior: {
    name: "Warrior",
    cost: 8
  },
  wizard: {
    name: "Wizard",
    cost: 9
  },
  trader: {
    name: "Trader",
    cost: 10001
  }
};
export default function App({ login }) {
  const [lastUsed, setLast] = useState(0);
  const [freePoints, setFreePoints] = useState(100);
  const [charClass, setCharClass] = useState("");
  console.log("last", lastUsed, "freePo", freePoints, "charcls", charClass);
  const handleClassChange = (e, value) => {
    const cls = e.target.value;
    const refund = freePoints + lastUsed;
    const cost = value.cost;
   //Calculate with refund
    const query = refund - cost < 0;
    const error = "You do not have enough free points!";
    const cause = refund - cost;
    if (query) {
      toast.error(error, {
        position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        draggable: false,
      });
    } else {
      setLast(cost);
      setCharClass(cls);
      setFreePoints(cause);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(availableClasses).map(([key, value]) => (
        <div key={key} className="form-control">
          <label className="label cursor-pointer">
            <span className="label-text">
              {value.name} - {value.cost}p
            </span>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="charClass"
              value={key}
              className="radio checked:background-green-500"
              checked={key === charClass}
             //Pass value here itself
              onChange={(e) => handleClassChange(e, value)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```